# IntentService for background task

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I'm planning to use an IntentService to do some processing. The service is started from a broadcast receiver registered in the manifest. The service has to update a db so the operation can be long (even a minute). For the cpu I can take a wakelock but about the OS?

1. Is it possible to call startForeground on an intentservice?
2. An intentservice is created again after the kill? What is the default behaviour? START_STICKY?
3. The service grab a db lock (ReentrantReadWrite java lock) to avoid concurrent access, if the service is killed, the lock is freed? if not, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As `IntentSerivice` extends `Service` there's nothing stopping you from calling `startForeground()`. You will have to show an actual notification though (There used to be a hack that enabled foreground service without a notification, but luckily it was fixed in 4.3).
2. The default behavior for `IntentService` is `START_NOT_STICKY`. You can change it by calling [`setIntentRedelivery(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#setIntentRedelivery(boolean)) in your constructor, or elsewhere.
3. `ReentrantReadWrite` is a java level lock, not a file/db/OS level lock. This means that once the process is dead the lock is gone. (You did say 'a db lock` but I assume it's just inaccurate wording - you're not locking the DB somehow, are you?).

Comment: No, db lock means just grabbing a write lock in the db class :)